# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, django

I start my Django project, migrate my databases, and after there I run my server for testing.

If I run the server in my Django project in Python...

```
(venv) C:\PR\djangogirls>manage.py runserver

Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 03, 2015 - 00:59:05
Django version 1.7.7, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK
```

I get this error:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 03, 2015 - 00:59:05
Django version 1.7.7, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x00000000045897B8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PR\djangogirls\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", li
ne 222, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\PR\djangogirls\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands
\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading)
  File "C:\PR\djangogirls\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py
", line 176, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\PR\djangogirls\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py
", line 117, in __init__
    super(WSGIServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 430, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\PR\djangogirls\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py
", line 121, in server_bind
    super(WSGIServer, self).server_bind()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 135, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 464, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: You input params that it should be `utf-8` code. You'd better give code.

Comment: i do not understand you.
You want to tell me all the files buyout brought in cmd.
I have to write each of them on top `#coding:utf-8` 
yes or no???

Comment: I guess it is related to the server name. `gethostbyaddr(name)` tries to get your server name which might be your laptop name containing international characters and thus it fails?

Comment: Try to set your Windows computer name to contain only ASCII characters.

Comment: And +1 for choosing djangogirls!

Comment: I think you save your file format should be `utf-8 without BOM`.

Comment: if i creat a new user in my Window, fix corrected?

Comment: what is BOM? How to save utf-8 without BOM?

Comment: Please use Notepad++, and choose `Encoding`, you can `Covert to UTF-8 without BOM`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to open your source file by notebook.Choose the file coding:UTF-8.Then save your file as a new file.Reload the new file and you can fix this error.

Comment: this could be a comment

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with your computer name, not the user’s name. I have experienced the same problem before. After I changed the computer name to an English name the problem was resolved. I think the issue is the name of the port. When my computer's name is `'书房台式计算机`'，, Django reads the port as `'书房计算机：8000`' and reports an error.

When I changed the computer name to `'Gaara`' the port’s name changed to `'Gaara:8000'` and didn't return an error.