# django manage.py runserver fails to run

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Im new to django, i started a project inside a virtualenv and whenever i try to runserver i get this message:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 01, 2018 - 13:22:34
Django version 2.0.2, using settings 'PollApp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.
<locals>.wrapper at 0x03BBF7C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Desarrollo\HelloWorld1\lib\site-
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Desarrollo\HelloWorld1\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 143, in 
inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Desarrollo\HelloWorld1\lib\site-
packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 163, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Desarrollo\HelloWorld1\lib\site-
packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\sebastian\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "c:\users\sebastian\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
32\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "c:\users\sebastian\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
32\Lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "c:\users\sebastian\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-
32\Lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 7: 
invalid continuation byte
```

I dont realy know where to start solving this error, i have a WAMP server installed, should i check if im using the 8000 port?

Comment: Check your computer name. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423734/) or [this page](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xcf-solved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to known issues bellow, your best solution will be changing your host name.
I don't WAMP is causing this, unless they are running on the same PORT!

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19357

https://bugs.python.org/issue26227

[Error while running Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324014/error-while-running-django-app)

Answer (score 3):

Change your computer name so it only has valid ASCII characters